# Build an accde from accdb from command line?

Tags: powershell, ms-access, build

[Very similar to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464839/build-an-access-executable-from-command-line) but I want to build an `.accde` from an `.accdb` file and try to integrate this into a DevOps pipeline. Is this possible maybe with maybe powershell or basic cmd commandS?

Comment: You should be able to translate the second answer on your linked post to vbscript or PowerShell easily...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to an undocument command that does this job (VBS)

```
Dim app
Dim strDBName
Dim strADEName

Set app = CreateObject("Access.Application")
strDBName = "Path_To_YourAccdb.accdb" 'e.g C:\Temp\Myapp.accdb
strADEName = "nameOf_The_Compiled.accde" 'e.g. C:\Temp\MyApp.accde

app.SysCmd 603, CStr(strDBName), CStr(strADEName)

Set app = Nothing
```

Just put the above is a vbscript and it will do the job just fine
Taken from here : https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=make-access-accde-vb-script

Comment: So I converted your answer above to powershell, but when running the `.SysCmd(603, $appName, $dbName)` I get the following: `Cannot convert argument "Action", with value: "603", for "SysCmd" to type 
"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction": "Cannot convert value "603" to type 
"Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcSysCmdAction" due to enumeration values that are not valid. 
Specify one of the following enumeration values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "ac
SysCmdInitMeter,acSysCmdUpdateMeter,acSysCmdRemoveMeter,acSysCmdSetStatus,acSysCmdClearStatus, ..."."`

Comment: How about running the VBs to ensure on your system the solution works and then transfer it to PS

Comment: I really wanted to put this in a "build" pipeline, that's why. Unless you know something I don't, that would mean including this vb tool as an executable in my pipeline. As opposed to running a powershell script.

Comment: How about turning to an .exe ?